# how to find exact file without listing folders

Tags: bash, find

my current folder is the top of the folder tree structure
somewhere inside I have an *.rpm file.

how do I find that *.rpm file in a way that'll list only its full path when found and not list every folder it searches recursively?

Comment: `rpm`? You are not using redhat are you?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest method would be to use `locate`. It will only show the actual file (and directory):

```
$ locate Screenshot\ from\ 2013-02-13\ 22\:36\:33.png 
/home/rinzwind/Screenshot from 2013-02-13 22:36:33.png
```

On Ubuntu locate is updated once every do often so it might not find very recent files. You can force an update by issueing a ...

```
sudo updatedb
```

Answer (score 3):

try `find . -name [filename]` or `find . | grep name`.
find is very useful. You can for example execute commands on your find results `find . - name [file to chmod ] -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

Comment: To have `find` output the absolute path: `find "$(pwd)" -name filename`